# Xamarin android App Deployment failing with error "apksigner.BAT" exited with code 2

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment

Xamarin App Deployment failing with error "apksigner.BAT" exited with code 2 .

JDK version 1.8.162

Comment: The error seems to be because of latest JDK versions only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downgrading the JDK to 1.8.131.

i faced the problems with 1.8.161 and 1.8.162.

If u are using JDK 9, then downgrade to JDK-8

Comment: if that doesnt work, just install 1.8.131 in addition to the existing one

Comment: @John: do 1 thing, just use the existing JDK161, 32bit version.
add the configs and Environment variable for that only. just install the JDK131 additionally ; no need to set any configuration for JDK131

Comment: Pleasure remove any space in the SDK locations.

Comment: In my VS2017 with jdk1.8.0_161 there was the same error. In VS2015 with jdk1.6 - there is no. JDK version is a real reason. Tried several devices and systems before found the issue after updating VS.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling JDK 9.x fixed it for me.

That Android Settings were pointing a JDK 8.x made no difference. JDK 9.x had to be removed to fix the issue.

Comment: Solved!  You just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when building a Xamarin.Android app on Visual Studio.

It was caused by having migrated my keystore from JKS to PKCS12 format because

`keytool.exe -list -v -keystore <path to my keystore>`

kept giving me the following `Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format`.

Bad idea to migrate, it appears `apksigner.BAT` requires the keystore be in the JKS format. I solved this issue by reverting back to my `debug.keystore.old`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **JDK** related answers above which is correct, also try to check PATH variable. There have to be latest installed JDK version. Solved my problem after days of checking different IDE's, machines and devices.

Answer (score 0):

As others found, it's a conflict that occurs when you have a newer version of Java installed, such as JDK 9.

This shouldn't really be necessary but here is a workaround: Create a new batch file with the below content (update paths as necessary).  You want to set JAVA_HOME so it points to the older version of Java.

**Xamarin.bat:**

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\"
start devenv.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently get an old poject from a client. It was giving same `error` in `Visual Studio for Windows`. In `Visual Studio for Mac` it was giving 1 error `without displaying` any `Error Message`.

The reason `behind` the `error` was that the client have specified a `signing key` which is `not available` on my `system`.

On `Mac` I just have to `uncheck` the `apk signing` option.

while on `Windows` I have to `edit` the `csproj` file to remove the `signing key`. Now the project builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked removing (or renaming) apksigner.bat from my current build tools directory (...AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc1\apksigner.bat)

After then, cleaned obj and Debug/Release directory->Rebuild->Deploy