# Build Failed - apksigner.BAT exited with code 2

Tags: deployment, build, xamarin.android, apk

I am having error when generating apk in Xamarin. I have checked solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296427/xamarin-android-app-deployment-failing-with-error-apksigner-bat-exited-with-co) but my JDK version is already jdk1.8.0_131. Here is the my set-up.

Android Setting:
[image]

Environment Variables:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: of course many times

Comment: Do you have other JDKs? Please remove them. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123554/any-new-demo-project-deployment-keeps-failing-visual-studio-2017